# How to change screenshots to save as low res JPG instad of PNG On Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, screenshot, quicksilver

On Mac OS X how can I change screenshots to save as low res JPG insetad of a PNG? I also have quicksilver installed and use the "capture region" shortcut quite often - not sure if that would have any effect on the answer here.

**UPDATE:**

The answer below is great for getting a jpg version. Thanks!

But is there some way to get a low res version though? Or possibly a script I could use to convert to a low res version? Maybe with quicksilver? Or a screen cap utility that would allow me to set the jpg quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaults write com.apple.screencapture type jpg` to change the default format.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /2/screenshots/
x=$(date +"%y%m%d%H%M%S")
screencapture -i -o $x.png
sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 60 $x.png -o $x.jpg
rm $x.png
```

`screencapture` flags:

- `-i` = interactive / selection
- `-o` = no shadows in window mode

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer! If I wanted to convert it to black and white, how would I do that?

Comment: Install ImageMagick (for example `sudo port install imagemagick`), and `convert  <image> -colorspace Gray <image>` or `convert <image> -fx '(r+g+b)/3' <image>`.

Answer (score 2):

Lifted from [here](http://guides.macrumors.com/Taking_Screenshots_in_Mac_OS_X): in 10.4 and up you can change the format used for the screen shot image by editing some hidden options. Open up Terminal and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type image_format
killall SystemUIServer
```

Where `image_format` can be one of the following: jpg, tiff, pdf, png, bmp or pict. The article mentions "among others" so other format options might be possible too.

So in your case:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type jpg
killall SystemUIServer
```

would get you JPEG screen shots instead of PNG.

The resolution or quality of the image does not appear to be configurable. I'm pretty sure you get a 1:1 pixel capture. For example, I just took a Cmd-Shift-3 capture of my iMac desktop and file info is telling me the image is 1900 x 1200 pixels -- exactly the same size as my screen resolution.

Comment: Thanks! Anybody else have some ideas on a way to get a low res version?

Comment: I gave you an upvote for the default image type, but the low res is more important to me so I've accepted Lri's answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out https://getcleanshot.com/ is doing exactly that. It has a setting:

[image]